# Open firefox from bash file "Error: no display specified"

Tags: bash, firefox, cron

I need to open a browser and access my server with the ip address 1.2.3.4. First I ping my server and if the ping did not fail I launch the home page in a browser. For this I have written a bash file as follows:

```
# add ip / hostname separated by white space
myHost=1.2.3.4

# no ping request
COUNT=1

count=$(ping -c $COUNT $myHost | grep 'received' | awk -F',' '{ print $2 }' | awk '{ print $1 }')
if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then
# 100% failed
echo "Host : $myHost is down (ping failed) at $(date)"
else
    firefox $myHost
fi
```

But I am getting an error message 
`Error: no display specified`. Firefox is not launching. What am I doing wrong.

This file is getting called every 5 minutes using a `cronjob`. The `cronjob` seems to be  working fine.

Comment: This question was asked and solved (Feb 2014) long before the "duplicate question" was asked  (Aug 2014).  So I don't know why this is marked duplicate and why people are answering to this even now. Should I close this as solved ? How do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to specify the display.

Add this to your script before running firefox

```
 export DISPLAY=:0
```

your script would be like:

```
#add ip / hostname separated by white space
myHost=1.2.3.4
export DISPLAY=:0
# no ping request
COUNT=1

count=$(ping -c $COUNT $myHost | grep 'received' | awk -F',' '{ print $2 }' | awk '{ print $1 }')
if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then
# 100% failed
echo "Host : $myHost is down (ping failed) at $(date)"
else
    firefox $myHost
fi
```

Comment: I tried adding  export DISPLAY=:0, but now it is showing an error :        'No protocol specified. 
         Error: cannot open display: :0'. What am I missing?

Comment: reboot and then try again

Comment: Yes, rebooted my PC itself. Still the same error.

Comment: "export DISPLAY=:0" and then I did a "xhost +" and now its working fine. I also did a "/usr/bin/firefox $myHost". Now its working fine. Thank you

Comment: Just to further clarify for anyone else that comes along: You need to run 'xhost +' once from a terminal in ubuntu, and then you can launch GUIs (firefox) remotely (ssh,vboxmanage guestcontrol, etc)